# Is there a way to detect when a user taps on Google's tool bar ( All | Images | Apps | Videos | etc... ) on UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am building an app and I am using a `UIWebView`. When Google is displayed on this `UIWebView` I want two different behaviors based on :

- the user taps on the tool bar ( see screenshot for the definition of this "tool bar", I didn't know how to call it )
- the user taps on any other link on the page

[image]

So my question : is there a way to know if a user tapped on this tool bar or if he/she tapped somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that's not really clean but works for my use case. I just want to load the page if the user taps on the tool bar and not if he / she taps anywhere else. So this suits my need :

```
    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
    {
        if let requestUrl = request.URL
        {
            if let requestHost = requestUrl.host
            {
                if requestHost.containsString("www.google.")
                {
                    // Google link
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```